# Back button is gone in split view

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

After embedding the **UISplitViewController** inside a **UITabViewController**, back button on navigation bar is turned into a full screen icon:
[image]

It's the segue preparation code:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDrugDetails" {
        //foo
        controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem
        controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = 
    }
}
```

How can I get back the back button? (everything works fine on iPhone)

Edit: Storyboard
[image]

Comment: Are you sure the splitViewController is embeded inside a table view controller? I suppose is the contrary.

Comment: @Gabriel I have updated the question with an image